# postgresql with recursive grabs whole table

Tags: sql, postgresql, categorization

I have the following postgresql structure

```
\d brand_categories;
                                Table "public.brand_categories"
        Column        |  Type   |                           Modifiers
----------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer | not null default nextval('brand_categories_id_seq'::regclass)
 category_code        | text    | not null
 correlation_id       | uuid    | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 created_by_id        | integer | not null
 updated_by_id        | integer | not null
 parent_category_code | text    |
```

I am trying to get all the parents and childs of a category via `WITH RECURSIVE` but not take siblings of a category. I tried to do the following (inside ruby code):

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_categories(category_code) AS (
  SELECT category_code FROM brand_categories
    WHERE category_code = 'beer'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT children.category_code FROM brand_categories AS parents, brand_categories AS children
      WHERE parents.category_code = children.parent_category_code AND parents.category_code != 'alcohol'
    UNION SELECT parents.category_code FROM brand_categories AS children, brand_categories AS parents
      WHERE parents.category_code = children.parent_category_code
)
SELECT * from included_categories
```

The problem is that it takes the whole set of categories even though most are completely unrelated. Is there something wrong in this query?

Note that this is a simple categorization with a depth of 2 or 3.

Comment: Did you try make your query direct in postgresql? I mean want to be clear if you need help making the query or translate to ruby

Comment: Then maybe you should post the query you try in postgresql instead the one using ruby. Also try provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer even faster

Comment: Your recursive query (the `SELECT` after the `UNION ALL`) is joining two copies of `brand_categories`. It should be joining `brand_categories` to `included_categories`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I edited out the ruby part to give an example of query instead. I'll play with SqlFiddle tomorrow if I don't get any answer.

Comment: @NickBarnes if I do that I get `ERROR:  recursive reference to query "included_categories" must not appear within its non-recursive term`.

Answer (score 1):

My boss helped me to solve the problem, it made more sense to do it in 2 parts:

- Find all parents
- Find all children

Here is the sql:

```
WITH RECURSIVE children_of(category_code) AS (
  SELECT category_code FROM brand_categories WHERE parent_category_code = 'alcohol'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT brand_categories.category_code FROM brand_categories
    JOIN children_of ON brand_categories.parent_category_code = children_of.category_code
),
parents_of(parent_category_code) AS (
  SELECT parent_category_code FROM brand_categories WHERE category_code = 'alcohol'
  UNION
    SELECT brand_categories.parent_category_code FROM parents_of
    JOIN brand_categories ON brand_categories.category_code = parents_of.parent_category_code
)
SELECT category_code FROM (SELECT * FROM children_of UNION SELECT parent_category_code FROM parents_of) t0(category_code)
  WHERE category_code IS NOT NULL
```